# Showing Values higher than average and field data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to print the name and the budged of those Zoos with budget higher than average, I've tried lots of ways of doing it but some don't work at all, now I tried this one but shows every zoo and budged when I need only the name and budged of those higher than average

*code*

````sql
select (nombrezoo), avg(presupuesto)
from zoo
group by presupuesto
order by presupuesto asc
where presupuesto > avg(presupuesto)```

Everything is in the same table
````

Comment: Some example data/output? What is the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *subquery* in the `where` clause:

```
select nombrezoo, presupuest
from zoo
where presupuesto > (select avg(presupuesto) from zoo)
order by presupuesto asc
```

Comment: lol i thought of it but didn't actually think that structure might do it, thanks in advance.

Comment: Any clue of how I could also apply format currency for the presupuesto column?

Comment: @StalingMarin . . . You should ask a new question with sample data and desired results.